# Unable to install bbplot package in R

Tags: r, github, package, devtools

I am unable to install "bbplot" package, I thought to install through devtools package, but it is not downloading as well. The following error appears while installing "devtools";

> Warning in install.packages :
>     error 1 in extracting from zip file
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     cannot open compressed file 'DT/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
>   Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

I have also tried to download using the following method but no success:

```
 path <- "https://github.com/bbc/bbplot"

install.packages(path, repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

The following error appears, while installing through above method:

> Error in getOctD(x, offset, len) : invalid octal digit
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘C:/Users/work/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpyC6V4z/downloaded_packages/bbplot’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Perhaps you should try `devtools::install_github(path)`?

Comment: The devtools package must be installed first.   You can type the following to show your list of installed packages:  libarary().   This will show whether you have the devtools package installed.  If you just installed the devtools package, restart R Studio.

Answer (score 0):

For the beginning user who is not familiar with loading packages into R Studio, you will need to do the following in this order:  1) install the devtools package.  2) Restart R Studio  3) Open the devtools library   4) Use devtools to install the BBplot package  5) Run the bbplot package

```
install.packages("devtools")   # Adds the devtools package to R Studio library

# Reboot Computer

libaray(devtools)                   # opens the devtools 
devtools::install_github('bbc/bbplot')    # Uses devtools to install bbplot package

library(bbplot)                    # opens bbplot
```

Comment: I've done it just fine without steps 2-3, and I *certainly* do not think `Reboot Computer` is required. (Even by your code, you don't need 3, since you use `devtools::install_github` instead of just `install_github`. I personally prefer *not* loading `devtools`, even though I use it daily.)

Comment: I am receiving this error while installing GITHUB Library: Warning in install.packages 
  cannot open compressed file 'roxygen2/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

Comment: Hi, on my Windows 10 PC, the path to the R library is: C:\Program Files\R\R3.6\library.  On several occasions I needed to delete an entire R package from the library folder.  See if you have a partially  installed devtools library.  If so, just delete it and repeat the install process.